# Only a solid red light and no ethernet lights after broken script

Tags: pi-3b+

Model: Pi 3 B+

I wrote a script using GPIO pins and I'm fairly certain there was no way for it to cause a short circuit. I ran the script, and was unable to stop it using ctrl+c, so I pulled the plug on the Pi and when I tried plugging it back in, all I got was a solid red light. The ethernet lights are also not on when I have an ethernet cable plugged in. I've tried recovering the SD card by reformatting it and reinstalling the saved disk image, and also tried putting a blank copy of NOOBS on it, but it still isn't working. I used a voltmeter to test the GPIO pins, and the 5V is working. The 3v3 doesn't seem to be working, however...

Any thoughts? Do I just need to get a new Pi? I just got this a few weeks ago and would hate to have to redo everything.

Comment: You’ve killed your Pi. What did you have connected to the GPIO?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no 3.3V the Pi is DEAD!

No script can damage the Pi (although it can corrupt the OS - as can pulling the plug).

NOTE poking a voltmeter at the header pins is a BAD idea. Even it the Pi wasn't dead, a momentary short between the 3.3V & 5V pins (which are adjacent) is invariably fatal.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> I wrote a script using GPIO pins and I'm fairly certain there was no
>   way for it to cause a short circuit.

***Answer***

> Well, if you are connecting a GPIO pin to any pin of a 5V powered
>   device, then there is risk of frying the Rpi or shortening it life。 
>   You might like to read the following posts for more details.

[DHT11 sensor and the wrong voltage may have fried my RPi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/dht11-sensor-and-the-wrong-voltage-may-have-fried-my-rpi3) [***Rpi Latching Up Instant Suicide***]

[image: latch up problem]

[Circuit wiring issue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97949/circuit-wiring-issue) [***Rpi Latching up Slow Suicide***]

[Reading Output signal from external circuit using Rpi GPIO Pin](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96564/reading-output-signal-from-external-circuit-using-rpi-gpio-pin)

[Rpi Latch Up Discussion Notes 1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=232411&p=1426931&hilit=latch%20up%20tlfong01#p1424642)

[Rpi Latch Up Discussion Notes 2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=232411&p=1426931&hilit=latch%20up%20tlfong01#p1426931)

[Rpi 5V Low Trigger Relay Latching Up Risk Notes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=232411&hilit=latch%20up%20tlfong01&sid=cf28da54e634c074b9b2ce7f39591614#p1422957)

[image: relay latch up]

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - Warning on dangerous pulling up GPIO pin to 5V*

[GPIO Electrical Specifications Raspberry Pi input and output pin voltage and current capability - Mosiac Documentation Web](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications)

[image: latch up problem]

*GPIO pin circuitry*

> The internal diodes shown in the figure are not really substrate
>   diodes, but they are actually parasitic FETs.
>
> Electrically, their I-V characteristic looks like a diode's, but with
>   a greater forward drop and a more gradual knee.
>
> They may protect against low current transient events caused by
>   transient out-of-range voltages applied to the pins, but they are not
>   intended to protect against the application of voltages greater than
>   the supply voltage or less than ground, even with an external series
>   resistor.

*In brief, you should never deliberately forward bias those "diodes".*

> Consequently, you can not safely place an external pull-up resistor to
>   5V on the I/O pin. That would forward bias a parasitic FET and owing
>   to its poor internal impedance to the chip's internal power rail it
>   may overheat, or worse, it may bias up parts of the chip to voltages
>   greater than they can handle.

***So, don't do it!***