# GPIO pins do not appear to go into the raspberry pi

Tags: gpio

I am testing out this new birthday present I got ages ago and I this set I have got has got male pins and the raspberry pi's GPIO pins are male as well and they obviously appear to not go in.

This diagram explains what the issue is
[image]

all of the wires going in are males and the numbered GPIO pins in the raspberry pi are all male as well

[image]

These are what the cables look like

Comment: Buy some 'female to male dupont jumper wires'

Comment: @CoderMike I have looked those up and those are not what I need the cable I am trying to connect up to the raspberry pi looks like this.

Comment: Just google them! https://www.amazon.co.uk/Elegoo-120pcs-Multicolored-Breadboard-arduino-colorful/dp/B01EV70C78/ref=pd_lpo_vtph_147_bs_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=GVW3W71P9Y1SS5G6XBH6

Comment: The other thing is that this hardware could is risky using and if it goes wrong it can destroy the rasbperry pi. looks at this link: http://guides.cyntech.co.uk/snap-circuits/snap-circuit-analog-input-pwm-output/

Comment: @CoderMike ok i will buy them

Comment: @CoderMike Is it possible to get a few less than that because I only need about 20 female to females altogether

Comment: Your 10 cables look like those for ECG.  They are 10 lead cables for 12 lead ECG (yes, 10 leads for 12 lead ECG.  It is indeed confusing). One end of the cable leads to the ECG equipment, and the other end leads to your heart.  You might have an heart attack if your mislead your lead to the Rpi! :) Is your birthday present from an ECG guy? - https://yk-med.world.taobao.com/category-1348917403.htm?spm=a312a.7700824.w4010-3542484999.14.1b462432rGkmZw&search=y&parentCatId=451195248&parentCatName=%B5%BC%C1%AA%CF%DF&catName=Holter-%B6%AF%CC%AC%B5%BC%C1%AA%CF%DF#bd

Comment: @tlfong01 My first thought was they are for something contact capacitative (does an ECG count as such, lol?), like those pianos made of fruit: https://www.instructables.com/id/Quick-Fruit-Piano/

Comment: The birthday present might be the AD3235 ADC based heart beat monitor.  Ecg module AD8232 ecg measuring pulse heart ecg monitoring module sensor kit - US$4.36
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/Ecg-module-AD8232-ecg-measurement-pulse-heart-ecg-monitoring-sensor-module-kit/32228816701.html?spm=a2g0w.search0104.3.1.2d863212rlBHCL&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_9_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=8dac754c-d377-4cac-8fc7-acc05d990120-0&algo_pvid=8dac754c-d377-4cac-8fc7-acc05d990120

Comment: The AD8232 ADC is dirt cheap, but it uses very advanced technology and is actually being used in high precision mission/life critical medical applications.  Raspberry Pi 3B+ interface with Heart Monitor AD8232 using MCP3008 and SPI pins
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96482/raspberry-pi-3b-interface-with-heart-monitor-ad8232-using-mcp3008-and-spi-pins

Comment: @tlfong01 No its nothing like that. It's not an ECG. its a circuit wire. They are called snap circuits and I am trying to just connect them to my raspberry pi!

Comment: @goldilocks no its nothing like that. It's not an ECG. its a circuit wire. They are called snap circuits and I am trying to just connect them to my raspberry pi!

Comment: Sounds a bit like "instant tea", which is a real product which you place in boiling water and stir, but distinct from real tea, which you place in boiling water and stir ;)  Point being a regular breadboard and jumper wires are pretty easy to use and accomplish the same thing, so don't feel bound by the snaps.  Have fun!

Comment: @ Digital_Rookie Thank you for your reply.  So I have googled to learn more.

Comment: @Digital_Rookie  I think if you wish to connect Rpi to your snap circuits, you can do one of two things: (1) convert the needle end of the button wire to Rpi compatible DuPont female sockets. (2) buy button wires, to convert them - https://www.google.com/search?q=aliexpress+ECG+3.5mm+button+wire&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=if__GHocsH29hM%253A%252Ct4Ipg1WgpXlv2M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRQs2f5DuxULf78y2vsu2uUFSnDHw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUvcOVoM_iAhXY62EKHRtWBwUQ9QEwA3oECAAQCg#imgrc=_&vet=1

Comment: If needle end button wires can fit female socket of DuPont then it would be prefect, no modifications necessary. https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/40-pi-ces-fil-de-raccordement-Dupont-ligne-de-c-ble-2-54mm-femelle-femelle-Dupont/32963194649.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.34.5ad01d352WIW8Y&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_0_10084_10083_10887_10307_321_453_322_454_10618_536_10065_317_537_10068_319_10059_10103_10884_10696%2Csearchweb201603_0%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=bbe0856f-e1ca-499e-aa04-f5b9ff454362&algo_expid=bbe0856f-e1ca-499e-aa04-f5b9ff454362-4

Answer (score 3):

Digital_Rookie -- Welcome.

The (obvious) answer would be to get female to female  cables. I usually keep all three types of sets M-to-F, F-to-F, and M-to-M handy. eg.

[https://www.amazon.com/EDGELEC-Breadboard-Optional-Assorted-Multicolored/dp/B07GD2BWPY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GD2BWPY)

Comment: Is it possible to get a few less than that because I only need about 20 female to females altogether

Comment: @Digital_Rookie You can shop around, of course, but at some point the value of the product becomes too low to make it worth the shipping.  Sounds like you'll probably end up with more than you need.  This is the right answer though.  You just have the wrong cables and these (or any like them) should work.

Answer (score -2):

***Question***

> I am testing out this new birthday present I got ages ago
>   GPIO pins do not appear to go into the raspberry pi

***Answer***

*Introduction*

Ah, we never heard of the thing called "Snap Circuits", so everybody made wrong guesses.  In order to save our losing face and restore Rpi StackExchange's before damaged reputation, I am now preparing an answer.  I am a long winded guy, so the answer should be a bit long, perhaps 10 times longer than the average answer in this Q&A forum, ...

***Short Answer***

I usually first do some academic research, then some engineering experimentation, then make first draft of a short answer.  So I will now hop to the long answer part and hop back when the long answer is more or less complete, ...

*/ to continue, ...*

***Long Answer***

*/ to continue, ...*

***References***

[Snap Circuits - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_Circuits)

> Snap Circuits is a line of electronic kits manufactured by Elenco
>   Electronics and aimed at children eight years and older.
>
> The kits come in a variety of sizes, offering a range of building
>   experience for the user, and may include ***motors***, lamps and speakers.
>   The kits consist of a breadboard with prewired interconnections, into
>   which the various components can be snapped to easily create a working
>   circuit.
>
> Snap Circuits has been praised for exposing young children to
>   elementary ***engineering concepts***.

[image: snap circuit]

[Button Wire for Snap Circuits](https://www.google.com/search?q=aliexpress%20ECG%203.5mm%20button%20wire&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=if__GHocsH29hM%253A%252Ct4Ipg1WgpXlv2M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRQs2f5DuxULf78y2vsu2uUFSnDHw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUvcOVoM_iAhXY62EKHRtWBwUQ9QEwA3oECAAQCg#imgrc=_&vet=1)

[AliExpress 40 pieces Dupont 2.54mm Female to Female 20cm 1P-1P Jumper Wire - US$1](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/40-pi-ces-fil-de-raccordement-Dupont-ligne-de-c-ble-2-54mm-femelle-femelle-Dupont/32963194649.html?spm=a2g0w.search0302.3.34.5ad01d352WIW8Y&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_0_10084_10083_10887_10307_321_453_322_454_10618_536_10065_317_537_10068_319_10059_10103_10884_10696%2Csearchweb201603_0%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=bbe0856f-e1ca-499e-aa04-f5b9ff454362&algo_expid=bbe0856f-e1ca-499e-aa04-f5b9ff454362-4)

[Snap Circuits Extreme SC-750 full look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eROp66fWGxA)

[Snap Circuits Extreme - Model: SC-750](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCbxPMmWIrg)

[Snap Circuits Extreme SC-750 Review](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crHj-5DIgII)

Comment: I am confused what you are on about (I am only 14)

Comment: @Digital_Rookie - I am terribly sorry.  I wrongly thought that you got your birthday present at 12, and you were now over 16.  Please ignore my suggestions on modifying the snap wires for Rpi.  It is risky to connect Snap Circuits directly to Rpi, because the 3V to 6V battery power might damage the Rpi.  BTW, I included the Snap Circuits Youtube videos because I watched them and I am very impressed that teenagers can learn so much about electronics in such a very reasonably priced education kit.  My apologies again.  Happy electronics hobbying.