# I try to read analog signal with "AD8232" but it suddenly stopped working

Tags: boot, sensor, mcp3008

My setup is: "Raspberry Pi Zero W" + "MCP3008" + "AD8232" (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ad8232-heart-rate-monitor-hookup-guide/all).

A few days ago I was able to read ECG signal and print it on the monitor in python. But now when I connect electrodes to ad8232 it doesn't even detect my pulse (its diode isn't pulsing". Ad8232 still works perfectly fine with Arduino Uno.
I tested it also with my second raspberry pi zero w (same sd card) and it also doesn't work.

Could it be the fault of me putting this:

```
dtparam=spi=on
dtoverlay=mcp3008:spi0-0-present,spi0-0-speed=3600000
```

in my `/boot/config.txt` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem. It was noise from the grid. When I powered raspberry pi from laptop the sensor started working again. It's weird because earlier sensor was working even when I was powering it from the electrical grid.

Comment: Yes, grid noise often cause problems.  So I sometimes use 18650 rechargeable battery power banks for testing. See Points 2, 3 of my answer to the following question. (1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96482/raspberry-pi-3b-interface-with-heart-monitor-ad8232-using-mcp3008-and-spi-pins.  Cheers.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.