# How can we acquire an analog signal having both positive and negative parts , i.e. a bipolar signal, using Raspberry pi3 B+ module?

Tags: pi-3b+, sensor, analog-to-digital

I am using raspberry pi 3 B+ board. I have to acquire analog voltage signal having both positive and negative parts, i.e. a bipolar signal How can i acquire this signal with the R-pi?

I have tried with High precision AD/DA ADS 1256 board and ArPy extension boards. However none of them is capable of acquiring bipolar input analog signal.

Comment: I think ADS1256 can convert bipolar signals: 
Waveshare ADC Board negative value issue
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95843/waveshare-adc-board-negative-value-issue

Comment: And yes, ArPy's TCL2543 can only convert unipolar analogue signal, V+ to V- full scale, Vcc to Gnd max range only.

Comment: Nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Anwesha Khasnobish, BTW, your WaveShare board looks like his more intelligent elder sister Jetson: 
(1) Get Started with NVIDIA Jetson Nano Developer Kit
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uvu6NNOvhg4

(2) Waveshare Rpi AD/DA Board
https://www.waveshare.com/High-Precision-AD-DA-Board.htm

Comment: I am using  waveshare.com/High-Precision-AD-DA-Board board itself. ADs1256 is not able to read signals less than 0.1V. Thus most part of the negative signal is lost.

Comment: Is there any ADC expansion available for raspberry pi which can acquire bipolar analog signals

Comment: This question is not Pi specific, and no ADC can convert voltages exceeding its supply voltage, although there are established offsetting techniques and some which generate a negative reference.